# Socket read hangs in Java Applet run in Chrome

Tags: java, sockets, google-chrome, applet, freeze

I have a simple server that listens for connections and dumps 100k bytes of data when it gets tapped.

I have a corresponding client that makes a socket connection to the server, reads 100k bytes and exits.

Both report the transfers at 1k byte intervals.

If I run both in threads under Eclipse, they work fine.
If I run both as separate mains (using "java ..." in separate shells), they work fine.
If I run the server as a main and invoke the client from an applet running in Eclipse, they work fine.

***The problem:

If I run the server as a main and invoke the client as an applet in a Chrome browser running on the same (Windows) host as the server, they block after the server writes 24k bytes and the client reads about 9k bytes.

I'd like to build an applet that can get large files from a server, but this is making it difficult.

Because of the messages, I'm pretty sure the server is blocked by the unread output. I can't figure out why the client is blocked.

Comment: Update: The problem appears to be with the localhost socket connection. The file transfer works fine when the server code runs on one machine and the client code runs as an applet in a Chrome browser on another machine in the network.